# SwiftUI how change the binding item inside the NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationview

I have the data structure bellow:

```
    @State var datalist:[Data] = [1,2,3,4,5]
    var body:some View{
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                ForEach($datalist){$data in
                    NavigationLink{
                        DetailView($data)
                    }
                label:{
                    Text("123")
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have to use the bind cause I want to modify the data inside detailview, and inside the detailview is there a way to shift between the data like

```
struct DetailView{
@Binding var data //for example now is 3
function nextdata(){}// change it to 4
function previousdata(){}//change it to 5
}
```

Is this possible for a navigationlink?
If so, what is the best practice for doing it?

Comment: You already sketched out how to do it. What errors did you get exactly?

Comment: @Sweeper I can‘t find a way to get the other data from the datalist inside the navigationlink.

Comment: What you wrote - `ForEach($datalist){ $data in ... }` is exactly how you do that, provided that `datalist` contains `Identifiable` elements. I'll ask again, *what error did you get?* Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Oh, do you mean you want to go from the detail view of one data, to the detail view of another data?

Comment: Can you use a `NavigationStak` instead?

Comment: If you execute  nextData and move from 3 to 4 what would then happen to the DetailView that has a binding to 4 already? Maybe you should not have a ForEach loop here but only one DetailView instance and a couple of previous/next buttons that would changed the binding value for that single view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to display a list of this `Item` struct:

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: Int
    
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        number = value
    }
}
```

```
@State var items: [Item] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Give your `DetailView` the whole list of items, and the id of the item that it is currently displaying. The `DetailView` can find the item's index just by finding an item with that id using `firstIndex(where:)`.

```
ForEach(items){ item in
    NavigationLink{
        DetailView(items: $items, id: item.id)
    }
    label:{
        Text("\(item.number)")
    }
}
```

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var items: [Item]
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss // we will get to this
    @State var index: Int {
        didSet { id = item.id }
    }
    // the id of the currently displayed item
    @State var id: Item.ID
    
    var item: Item { items[index] }
    
    init(items: Binding<[Item]>, id: Item.ID) {
        _items = items
        _index = .init(initialValue: _items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!)
        _id = .init(initialValue: id)
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that if the list of `items` is constant, the code would be a lot simpler. You can use `ForEach` over the `items.indices` and get the indices that way.

In the `body` of `DetailView`, you can have buttons that go to the next/previous item. These buttons will change `index`, which changes `id` and the computed `item` property.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("\(item.number)")
        HStack {
            Button("Go Backwards") {
                index -= 1
            }
            .disabled(index == 0)

            // an example of mutating the current item in some way
            Button("Increment") {
                // when mutating, always use "items[index]" instead of "item"
                items[index].number += 1
            }

            Button("Go Forwards") {
                index += 1
            }
            .disabled(index == items.count - 1)
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: items.count) {
        updateIndex()
    }
}

func updateIndex() {
    if let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) {
        self.index = index
    } else {
        // this means the currently displayed item has been removed, so the detail view will be dismissed.
        dismiss()
    }
}
```

Note that when `items.count` changes, we recompute `index` by looking for an item with the current `id`. This is so that the currently displayed item doesn't change when some other code inserts an item to, or removes an item from `items`.